# Remove outliers from the lists of coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 2 lists `X` and `y` with ten coordinate values.

I also have 2 additional lists for point outliers: outlier_x and outlier_y.

I want to go over my X and Y lists, compare their coordinates with outliers and create new 2 lists (X_new and y_new) which will include points without outliers.

There is my nested loops where I stacked. It records only first point and sims doesn't move to the next point. Can you please help to fix it?

```py
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values
X = X.reshape(len(X),1)
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values

X_new = []
y_new = []
i = 0
n = 0
while i < len(X):
    while n < len(outlier_x):
        if (X[i] == outlier_x[n] and y[i] == outlier_y[n]):
            continue
        X_new.append(X[i])
        y_new.append(y[i])
        n+=
    i+=1
```

Here is my dataset:

```py
      x          y
0   0.0   0.998440
1   1.0   2.188544
2   4.0   7.572174
3   7.0   6.138442
4  11.0  11.737930
5   0.0   1.043314
6   1.0   1.733181
7   4.0   7.424136
8   7.0   6.138442
9  11.0   9.737930
```

And these points, which have been previously identified as outliers:

```py
      x          y
0   4.0   7.572174
1   7.0   6.138442
2  11.0  11.737930
3   4.0   7.424136
4   7.0   6.138442
```

Comment: You might want to create sets from your lists and use set operators to produce your desired result.

Comment: I`m not sure how to do it with sets. Probably still have to use nested loops

Comment: What's the rule that tells you whether a point is an outlier or not?

Comment: I have list of outlier have been determined previously (based on how far it is from polynomial regression curve). Anyway, I just need to compare this list with the list of all points and if they exactly match they have to be removed. I provided coordinates in the question.

Comment: @Kleogis were you helped by either of the provided answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Edit: Apologies, not only did I misunderstand your question I gave you a bad solution. Since you're checking for equality of your x,y coords in the outliers (as opposed to `<` `>`), then the following should work

```
X = [0, 1, 4, 7, 11, 0, 1, 4, 7, 11]   
Y = [0.99844039, 2.188544418, 7.572173987, 6.138441957, 11.73792995, 1.043313797, 1.733181475, 7.424136351, 6.138441957, 9.73792995]
outlier_X = [4, 7, 11, 4, 7]
outlier_Y = [7.572173987, 6.138441957, 11.73792995, 7.424136351, 6.138441957]
final_X = [] 
final_Y = []
for xi, yi in zip(X, Y):

    is_valid = not any([xi == ox and yi== oy  for ox, oy in zip(outlier_X, outlier_Y)])
    if is_valid:
        final_X.append(xi)
        final_Y.append(yi)

print(final_X)
print(final_Y)
```

Comment: I should be more specific about points. Some coordinates have same X values but different Y values.

Comment: That's fine, it shouldn't affect the solution. If two coordinates share the same x, but different y's, and one y is an outlier, than that point will be excluded, but the other x,y pair will not. Perhaps I'm not understanding though. Happy to take another look if something specifically didn't work. Cheers!

Comment: It returns empty array

Comment: Sorry, check the edited solution.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

```py
data[~np.isin(data, outliers).all(axis=1)]
```

### Steps

Starting with these two DataFrames:

```py
In [3]: data
Out[3]:
      x          y
0   0.0   0.998440
1   1.0   2.188544
2   4.0   7.572174
3   7.0   6.138442
4  11.0  11.737930
5   0.0   1.043314
6   1.0   1.733181
7   4.0   7.424136
8   7.0   6.138442
9  11.0   9.737930

In [4]: outliers
Out[4]:
      x          y
0   4.0   7.572174
1   7.0   6.138442
2  11.0  11.737930
3   4.0   7.424136
4   7.0   6.138442
```

We can use the `np.isin()` function to check if any row in `data` has any values that match with any row in `outliers`:

```py
In [5]: np.isin(data, outliers)
Out[5]:
array([[False, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True, False]])
```

Since we want a full match (both x- and y-coordinates), use `all()` along the first axis (across the columns):

```py
In [6]: np.isin(data, outliers).all(axis=1)
Out[6]:
array([False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  True,
       False])
```

This boolean mask tells us which rows match exactly with an outlier. All we need to do is invert the mask (since we want to filter outliers), and index into `data` with that mask:

```py
In [7]: data[~np.isin(data, outliers).all(axis=1)]
Out[7]:
      x         y
0   0.0  0.998440
1   1.0  2.188544
5   0.0  1.043314
6   1.0  1.733181
9  11.0  9.737930
```

From there, you can do whatever you like with the `x` and `y` columns.

### Alternate solution, starting with 1D arrays

If you have separate 1D arrays, `X` and `y`, and the same for the outliers, you can zip them into tuples and add them to a set and then subtract the outliers from the set:

```py
points = set(zip(X, y))
outliers = set(zip(outlier_x, outlier_y))
X_new, y_new = zip(*(points - outliers))
```

Comment: It gives error: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: Then you have multidimensional arrays. Please post a sample of actual array data, including the shape.

Comment: The data in csv file. Column A - # of points, column B - X coordinates, column C - y coordinates. The code to extract data:                                                                    dataset = pd.read_csv('D10.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values
X = X.reshape(len(X),1)
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values

Comment: @Kleogis see my updated solution, it is *much* better than using `for` loops, especially if your dataset is large.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution based on @sin tribu answer:

```
X_new = []
y_new = []

for xi, yi in zip(X, y):
    x_is_valid = all([xi != ox  or xi == ox for ox in outlier_x])
    y_is_valid = all([yi != oy and yi != oy for oy in outlier_y])
    if x_is_valid and y_is_valid:
            X_new.append(xi)
            y_new.append(yi)
```